# What would be an ideal outsourced/third party offsite backup vault solution?

Tags: backup, backup-restoration, data-recovery

Looking to find a service that offers rsync or dirvish abilities to do auto backups of my website and all content and databases into something like a data vault. Basically, rather than just a CDN to have an additional place to store files, I would like them stored just as a security backup (not delivered publicly like a CDN).

Otherwise, what would an ideal service that offers offsite data backup that specializes in the not for average consumer (as in no home PC files backup), more enterprise class data vault solutions, what would you feel the service should have?

Should it be a VM that you can login to? Or would it be ok if it was rsync which is initiated offsite by the vault servers for both backup and restore jobs that you have a web interface for to start/stop?

Answer (score 3):

Whatever backup solution you choose, if you have sensitive data to backup, you should be careful to use something that encrypts your data on the client side to protect it from hackers breaking into your server. Rsync does not do that. [Duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) would be better suited for the job.

I am using Duplicity plus a small wrapper perl script to backup about 10 Gig of data on a remote server. Works fine and it even gives me incremental backups, so I can recover data as it was n days ago.

Comment: rsync/dirvish over ssh keys can do.

Answer (score 0):

A service called [rsync.net](http://www.rsync.net/) offers what I believe you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

From a corporate/security point of view, [Iron Mountain](http://www.ironmountain.com/dataprotection/) is a great candidate.  They are very well respected and trusted, have a great reputation for securing corporate assets, and have been dealing with corporate data security issues for decades.

They purchased LiveVault (remember the John Cleese [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MgxgYL5P4z4)!) and have integrated it into their corporate data security and offsite storage offerings.

Answer (score 0):

Not to shamelessly plug, but I currently work in a company that offers this kind of service, and they aim slightly lower in price than IM.  You can message me for more details if you want.